# Managing animated images in PHP

Tags: php, png, edit, gif, animated

I would like to have some information about this topic. Everybody knows that it's possible to manage and even create images with PHPs gd-library, but is it possible to edit animated GIFs without losing the animation? Hope that someone is wise enough to answer this :)

Martti Laine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is said on the [website of Boutell, the original makers of GD](http://www.boutell.com/gd/faq.html) that there are animation functions to GD, but I have never seen them mentioned anywhere in the PHP manual.

There are several external classes to edit animated GIFs like [this one](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3234.html).

If your server supports it, however, I recommend [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), an external image processing solution. It can split animated GIFs into single files (see [here](http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/FAQ.html#C24)) and put them back together to an animation.

Additional GD resources:

- [How do I extract a single image from a multi-image file?](http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/FAQ.html#C32)
- [Animation basics](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/) in the GD manual
- [Animation modifications](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/) in the GD manual