# PHP GD Image - output animated GIF

Tags: php, gd, gif, animated

I have a animated GIF that I want as a watermark. How do I include an animated GIF? is this supported?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994969/managing-animated-images-in-php?rq=1

Comment: I have tried just loading the gif and then outputting it. My codes quite big (it's doing other stuff) - but I was looking if there was a simple example, or is this even possible?

Comment: I have the animated GIF, i just want to merge it with a jpeg

Comment: Do you want it to just overlay the jpg? Or actually be a watermark present when it's downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want It to be an actual watermark - present in the whole image when downloaded - then you'll have to convert the whole thing to a gif and overlay the background image (repeated every frame) with the watermark frames.

Do you have to have the animated watermark? Could you have a static watermark with the animated watermark positioned over the top of it?

At the end of the day, you can't animate a jpg, and having all your content saved as gifs is something I'd try and avoid